# how can I set the type before order confirm in magento 2 in phtml file

Tags: magento2, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-2.0.7

In magento 1

```
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
```

how can I set this in the magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
        /Magento/Msrp/Helper/Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }
```

inside function you can call,

```
public function msrpcall(){
    $this->helper->canApplyMsrp($product, Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply But i want in phtml file not in block with objectmanager can you tell me please how i set in phtml file

Comment: $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$msrp = $om->get('Magento/Msrp/Helper/Data')->canApplyMsrp($product, Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM));

Comment: Above formula is worked for you?

Comment: you can accept as answer so other community users can helpful in future.

Comment: @Rahulocodewire, Whats the issue have you faced?